# How to display post_types from each taxonomy with comment

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I am able to show taxonomy and post_type list under each taxonomy, however, i want to show 1 comment from each post_type as well but no success.

```
<?php 

$custom_terms = get_terms('article-category');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
wp_reset_query();
$args = array(
    'parent'=>0,
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'article-category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
        ),
    ),
 );

 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
 $comments = get_comments($args); // trying to get 1 comment for each post_type
 if($loop->have_posts()) {
    echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
        echo($comment->comment_content); // but not showing
    endwhile;
 }
}

?>
```

Below is an example that is working, it's showing each taxonomy as category and post_type as article 1, 2, 3 but I am not able to succeed on showing 1 comment from each post_type article. Each article has 1 comment only.

```
Category 1
 article 1 title
   1 recent comment from article 1  // this is not displaying

 article 2 title
   1 recent comment from article 2 // this is not displaying

 article 3 title
   1 recent comment from article 3 // this is not displaying

Category 2
 article 1 title
   1 recent comment from article 1 // this is not displaying

 article 2 title
   1 recent comment from article 2 // this is not displaying

 article 3 title
   1 recent comment from article 3 // this is not displaying
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'post_id' in the $args to get the comments.  An array of objects is returned if comments exist, then use the reset function to get the first comment.

```
$args = array( 'post_id' => 123 );
$comments = get_comments( $args );

if( $comments ) {
    $first_comment = reset($comments);
    echo $first_comment->comment_content
}
```